# How can I remove the first and second underline of a mp3 file using bash/sed script?

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

i have mp3's like **This_is_my_Mp3.mp3**
i would like to this **This is - my Mp3.mp3**

thanks for help

Comment: your title does not match the body of your question. What do you really want to do? [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain and simple:

```
% sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/ / - /2' <<<'This_is_my_Mp3.mp3'
This is - my Mp3.mp3
```

The /2 flag on the second expressions, that it will only replace the second occurence of the pattern.

When you work on 'fields' (which means that you work on text horizontally rather than vertically) `awk` usually is the better choice

If you want to bulk rename them, do the following:
This Version will just edit the stream, so you can see, what the result will be (no renaming files!):

```
for file in *.mp3; do
sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/ / - /2' <<<"$file"
done
```

With mv, this version will actually rename the file in the current directory (use with caution!):

```
for file in *.mp3; do 
mv "$file" "$(sed -e 's/_/ /g' -e 's/ / - /2' <<<$file)"
done
```